# Javascript how to use setFormula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How can i put variables in quotes in the `.setFormula`?

```
activeSheet.getRange(125,2).setFormula("=SOMME.SI($A$1:$A$40;"+text+";B1:B40)*B124");
```

My problem is that the variable text is a name and i need it to be in quotes as a condition. If not, the formula will not work and ill need to put `""` manualy

Can someone help with this ?

Comment: `"blahblah;\""+text+"\";blahblah"` OR `'blahblah;"'+text+'";blahblah'`...

Comment: thx for the quick answer it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you can use single quotes

```
activeSheet.getRange(125,2).setFormula("=SOMME.SI($A$1:$A$40;'"+text+"';B1:B40)*B124");
```

or even better use [string template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (notice the backticks)

```
activeSheet.getRange(125,2).setFormula(`=SOMME.SI($A$1:$A$40;"${text}";B1:B40)*B124`);
```